# firebase google and phone number signup user every time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I used firebase phone and google authentication in my app I am facing an issue that when a user logout and signing again though OTP or google it signup the user again by creating new user id and all the information that user update through profile update option erased and come back in original state as new user and all updates of profile lost.
**My phone sign in code is here**

```
 PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setTimeout(120L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(this)
            .setCallbacks(new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {


                    }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verifyId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(verifyId, forceResendingToken);

                    verificationId = verifyId;

                }
            }).build();

    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);


}

public void callNextScreen(View view) {
    dialog.show();

    String otp = binding.otpView.getText().toString();
    if (otp!= null) {
        verifyOTP(otp);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void verifyOTP(String otp) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otp);
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                String uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                String phoneNumber = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
                User users = new User();
                users.setPhone(phoneNumber);


                database
                        .collection("users")
                        .document(uid)
                        .set(users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(OTP_Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finishAffinity();
                        } else {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(OTP_Activity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });


            } else {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(OTP_Activity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**and my user attributes and user class constructor looks like this**

```
private String name, email, image, phone, gender;
private long coins = 500;

 public User(String name, String email, String image, String phone, String gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.image = image;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.gender = gender;
}
public User() {

}
```

this is how creating user profile with google signing

```
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken){

    AuthCredential firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        String uid = user.getUid();
                        User newUser = new User();
                        newUser.setName(user.getDisplayName());
                        newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                        newUser.setImage(user.getPhotoUrl().toString());

                      database
                                .collection("users")
                                .document(uid)
                                .set(newUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finishAffinity();
                                } else {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                     Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Signup Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       // updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo it works for sign up it create user profile. In my app user can update his profile but if a user logout and login again all updated details of user just vanish and it signup user again with new unique user id in firebase and those attributes of user which are null initially became null again